# VBScript in HTA, running sub from button unspecified error

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have this very simple HTA file that is basically a form that activates some powershell with parameters.

VBScript and some Javascript functions to stop the enter key from submitting the form & to pull data from the form:

```
<script>

    function grabData(name) {
        var txt_val;
        txt_val = document.getElementById(name).value;
        return txt_val;
    }

    $('html').bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            return false;
        }
    });

</script>

<script language="VBScript">

    Sub readFromServer()
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "processModel.bat """ & grabData("model") & """ """ & grabData("os") & """ """ & grabData("graphics") & """ """ & grabData("hdd") & """ """ & grabData("ram") & """ """ & grabData("processor") & """ """ & grabData("UPC") & """ """ & grabData("actualmodel") & """ """ & grabData("otherIdentifier") & """ "
        window.close()
    End Sub

</script>
```

Form elements:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="otherIdentifier">Bundle Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="otherIdentifier">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="model">Model</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="model" value="Surface 3">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="os">OS</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="os" value="Windows 10">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="graphics">Graphics</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="graphics" value="Intel(R) HD Graphics  ">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="hdd">HDD</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="hdd" value="125GB">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="processor">Processor</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="processor" value="Intel(R) Atom(TM) x7-Z8700  CPU @ 1.60GHz">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ram">RAM</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="ram" value="3.92">
</div>
```

Button that activates the vbscript:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onClick="vbscript:readFromServer()">Submit</button>
```

This is very similar to another page that functions exactly the same way, but this does not work.

When you click the button, you get an "Unspecified Error", and the line and Char lead me to the onClick function of the button, right after the colon.

[image]

I have no idea what is going wrong, but desperately need this to be working. What problem is my script having?

Comment: Do you launch some .bat from HTA to "activates some powershell with parameters"? Looks like that mess-up should be simplified at least to launch PS directly from HTA. Also it's not clear where the path to `output.bat` file came from, there is no such filename in the code.

Comment: @omegastripes None of that is really relevant except for the output.bat. output.bat is the HTA file I am running, its a batch hybrid.